# C# how to scan a folder and then store the scanned names as a string

Tags: c#, path, directory

I need to get a folder path some file that has the different name on every computer. For which I need to scan the folder that contain this file with  randomly generated name and then store the name of that folder as a string so that I can add to the path.

Here is my code:

```
string mypath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string mypath1 = @"\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\";
string mypath2 = //here is where i would like to scan the \Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ and store the folder inside as a string
string all_path = mypath + mypath1 + mypath2;
```

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. You wan't to get the name of the folder under Firefox\Profiles and store its absolute path ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the example at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc(v=vs.110).aspx will show you how to do what you want, it includes parsing and navigating subdirecties, including getting the name of them like you want.

Specifically the line:

```
string [] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(mpath1 + mypath2)
```